# Magento add prototype to xmlrpc

Tags: magento, prototype, xml-rpc

I tried to set order status by calling xmlrpc, but there's a issue, it thrown a excpetion "Calling parameters do not match signature".
because I use the following code to call api:

```
$client->call('call', array($session, 'api.setOrderStatus', $str));
```

and the correct way should be:

```
$client->call('call', array($session, 'api.setOrderStatus', array($str)));
```

the server doesn't accept 'string', Can I add 'string' type to prototypes?

```
$signatures = $info->getPrototypes();
    foreach ($signatures as $signature) {
        $sigParams = $signature->getParameters();
        if ($sigCalled === $sigParams) {
            $matched = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```